# Monitoring wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg for slow node

Tags: mariadb, galera

I'm monitoring the `wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg` status variable of a MariaDB Galera cluster to detect slow nodes within the cluster. However, whenever this value spikes the average queue size will stay high for days to weeks, depending on the uptime of the server (or last `FLUSH STATUS`).

According to the [MariaDB Galera documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg), the `wsrep_local_queue_avg` is an average since the last time the status command was run.

> Description: Average length of the receive queue since the most recent status query. If this value is noticeably larger than zero, the node is likely to be overloaded, and cannot apply the writesets as quickly as they arrive, resulting in replication throttling.

However, the [Galera Cluster](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/galera-status-variables.html#wsrep-local-recv-queue-avg) documentation contradicts this, and mentions

> Description: The maximum length of the recv queue **since the last FLUSH STATUS command**.

The latter seems to be the case. Because the recv queue average is just decreasing with fractions when checking it frequently. The behavior of average since last status check seems more desirable since we check this with an interval. If this triggers an alert and the issue is resolved afterwards, the check still thinks the service status is critical, since it's above a certain threshold. Unless `FLUSH STATUS` is executed.

Leaving me with two questions:

- Was this behavior changed in Galera, and in which version? I can't find it in changelog.
- Would it be viable to let the monitoring check execute `FLUSH LOCAL STATUS` after checking the average receive queue. In this case the checks execution in the next interval will contain data only of the time between the last check and the current check or is there a better way?

Version info:

- MariaDB Server: 10.2.33
- Galera: 25.3.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all of the `*_avg` status variables in Galera they an absolutely horrible design for all the reasons mentioned in your question. They are marginally useful for a developer testing things with a very small uptime but for any practical use I'd ignore all of them.

Lucky, for all of them, the raw amount is available.

For monitoring, use a decent graphing tool and configure it to monitor [wsrep_local_recv_queue](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_local_recv_queue) as a gauge.